# Find multiplicative inverses for elements in U(20)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am self-learning abstract algebra using *Abstract Algebra: An Introductory Course* by Gregory Lee.

I come across this group:

$$U(20)=\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$$

I have managed to find two pairs of multiplicative inverses, namely:

$$3\cdot 7=1$$
$$13\cdot 17=1$$

I am wondering how to find the multiplicative inverses for $9$, $11$, and $19$.

For example, for $19$, the closest I can get is:

$$9\cdot 19=11$$

Also, must inverse be unique in a group? In the other words, can two elements have the same inverse?

Thank you.

Comment: A number can be its own inverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In groups inverses are unique. $9$ and $11$ are their own inverses.  For $19$, it is also, since $19\equiv-1\bmod20$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it now.